# How to get the value for multiple buttons which is in a single form in Nodejs

Tags: node.js

I want to get the values of the buttons using req.body.[name] for multiple buttons. When I try this it shows the value undefined. But if I try with only one button it works fine. So I want to get the values for each button. 

Here is my code:

```
<form method="POST" action="/currentPatient">
    <table id="currentpatientslists">
      <tr>
       <td>Name</td>
       <td><button type="submit" value="delPatient" name="currentPatient">Release Patient</button></td>
       <td><button type="submit" value="medReport" name="currentPatient">Report</button></td>
       <td><button type="submit" value="medhistory" name="currentPatient">Medical History</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
```

nodejs code example:

```
function currentPatientHandler(req, res){

  const value = req.body.currentPatient;
  if(value == 'delPatient'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }

  else if(value == 'medReport'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }

  else if(value == 'medHistory'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }
}
```

What will be the correct approach to do this.

Comment: Can you include your node.js code too?

Comment: I suggest you to try 

    console.log(req.body)

 Look what you have...

Comment: @Angelotti I have already done this but it's showing undefined I put multiple buttons in the form. But If I put one button then it works fine

Comment: only request.body is undefined ?

Comment: @Angelotti yes console.log(req.body.currentPatient) is showing undefined

Comment: not console.log(req.body.currentPatient) but console.log(req.body)

Comment: @Angelotti it shows { currentPatient: 'delPatient' } if I click the button "Release Patient"

Comment: it seems it only get you the first button

Comment: if you give different name at the buttons?... or try to give and id at each button

Comment: @Angelotti if I give different id to each button then how can I get the id in nodejs. Can you please tell me?

Comment: ok sorry Id is not a good solution but try to give differente name at button like name="currentPatient1" at first name="currentPatient2" at second ecc.. and try to use console.log for each element like console.log(req.body.currentPatient1) and console.log(req.body.currentPatient2) ecc... look what happens

Comment: look also https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser to use body-parser

Answer (score 0):

It stated [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_value.asp) that if you use the  element in an HTML , different browsers will submit different values. Internet Explorer will submit the text between the  and  tags, while other browsers will submit the content of the value attribute.

I suggest using javascript with hidden input.

```
<form method="POST" action="/currentPatient" class="patientAction">
    <table id="currentpatientslists">
      <tr>
       <td>Name</td>
       <input type="hidden" name="currentPatient"/>
       <td><button type="button" class="patientAction" value="delPatient">Release Patient</button></td>
       <td><button type="button" class="patientAction" value="medReport">Report</button></td>
       <td><button type="button" class="patientAction" value="medHistory">Medical History</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
 </form>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
        let target = e.target;
        if (target.tagName === "BUTTON" && target.classList.contains('patientAction')) {
            document.querySelector('input[name="currentPatient"]').value = e.target.value;
            document.querySelector('form.patientAction').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Also don't forget to include bodyparser middleware on node.js side

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

or

```
let bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))`
```

Answer (score 0):

You definded **value = req.body.currentPatient**, but you need the value of the button So you should say **value.value**, like this:

```
function currentPatientHandler(req, res){

  const value = req.body.currentPatient;
  if(value.value == 'delPatient'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }

  else if(value.value== 'medReport'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }

  else if(value.value== 'medHistory'){
     res.redirect(//something);
  }
}
```